# VSCode displaying empty file after file size exceeds certain limit

Tags: visual-studio-code, line, special-characters

I am currently experiencing an issue with a file created during the iteration of a Bayesian model. The file contains information on the iterations, ranging from 1 to 20000, and various other data. However, once the file exceeds approximately 2000 lines, I am unable to view its contents in vscode. Although I am still able to open the file, nothing is displayed. Interestingly, when I open the file using a text editor, its contents are visible. Furthermore, if I remove the "[K" and "[A" characters (which I am unsure why they are present), the file becomes viewable in vscode again. This issue has only recently occurred and I was previously able to open the file, even when it contained 100000 rows.

```
iterations   0%|                          |  ETA: 6 days, 9:12:55 (18.39  s/it)[K
  iterations:  2[K
[A

[K[A
iterations   0%|                          |  ETA: 5 days, 22:40:52 (17.13  s/it)[K
  iterations:  3[K
[A

[K[A
iterations   0%|                          |  ETA: 5 days, 18:07:50 (16.58  s/it)[K
  iterations:  4[K
[A
```

Comment: are they ANSI color escape sequences, configure the tool that creates the file to not use color, after editing the question I saw there are Escape characters in the file, so they are ANSI color codes

Comment: Thanks. Knowing that these are ANSI color allowed me to use a plug-in to preview the file. But I will still like to have a solution to see the file, without a preview.
Unfortunately, the tool I'm using does not allow me to not use color.
Also, i do not understand three days ago worked without any problems.

Comment: you can configure the shell/terminal used to behave as a monochrome terminal/ no color, find a terminal id that is color less, then the tool should pick that up and stop using color codes